# What practical use cases are there for the static group comparison design?

Tags: experiment-design, pre-post-comparison

As far as I understand, the only difference between "the static group comparison design" and "the posttest-only control group design" is that the latter has randomized controlled trial (RCT), in other words we assign people randomly to the control group and the experimental group from given sample. RCT doesn't demand additional resources when we already have the control group and it eliminates influence of some biases, thus we should always perform it when we have the control group. Thus, from my point of view the static group comparison design doesn't make sense to use in practice, ever. But I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you give a reference for "the static group comparison design"?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Here you go: https://allpsych.com/researchmethods/preexperimentaldesign/  (look at the diagram too)